# putting moon glow on something

Tags: american-english

what does "putting moon glow on something" mean? I mean in this sentence I want to know what it means?
"I know I'm putting all this fucking moon glow on it now,like it was special and all."  I read it in a play.

Comment: Where did you find the sentence? What was the context?

Comment: @terdon  in a American play.

Comment: We need more context than that.  Perhaps you could tell us which play, so that we can look at the reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moon glow would refer to putting emphasis or light on something.

Comment: I did not read the play but moon glow can have several uses based on context.  It could mean to shed light on something that was unknown (dark).  Could also mean given light to something that maybe didn't deserve it - the light from the moon really comes from the sun....

Answer (score 3):

It suggests romance or a glorification. Taking the rough edges away. As a photographer, I might use a filter or a special effect to enhance something that might be rather ordinary. It sounds like something Holden Caldwell might have said from a J.D.Salinger novel. Youthful angst...